# Why can I not keep authenticating git with https after having added SSH key to Github?

Tags: git, github, ssh

- In the past, I've cloned repos with **https** authentication.
- Recently, I started using **SSH** authentication.
- When setting up SSH with Github, I also changed my main Github password.

Whenever I enter some old cloned repository on my local drive, which is still using https, I'm no longer allowed to e.g. git push:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': MYUSERNAME
Password for 'https://MYUSERNAME@github.com':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/USER/REPO.git/'
```

- The `.git/config` is untouched from back when the repository was cloned using https, so the `url` in this file is set to `https://github.com ...`
- I'm entering my NEW password.

I could now change the url in `.git/config` to use the SSH keys: `url = git@github...`. But I'd like to keep using https here. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure your password hasn't changed? Both protocols work fine for me, so I can't verify/reproduce this problem.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Yes, I changed my Github password since the repo cloning. But I'm entering that new password in the prompt when attempting e.g. a `git push`.

Comment: Can you try creating a new clone of any of your repositories over https and checking if your new password would work on that new clone?

Comment: Tried that. Still doesn't work with my password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this didn't have anything to do with SSH keys being added. I also added two-factor authentication (2FA) which was the reason I started having issues.

The solution is to create a token and use that instead of the password when managing a repository via HTTPS: https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors#provide-access-token-if-2fa-enabled

Answer (score 0):

SSH key is for SSH connection and not HTTP(S).

If your repository already has a remote repository setup with HTTP, you can easily change it with the command `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git`

Comment: This is what I currently do. I was wondering if there's no way I can continue using https for these old repositories which I once did clone via https. No?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you cloned with HTTPS and want to switch to SSH, you can use the command above. If you want to continue using HTTPS, you can continue using it by providing your usename and password each time you do a remote command (or by using a credential helper). It's not because you provided an SSH key, that you cannot use HTTP.

Comment: Exactly what I thought too. The problem I'm facing is 1) I wish to keep using https for this particular repository. 2) my password isn't accepted (as seen in my original post)

Comment: Ok, then you should probably contact github support. This case is working fine for me, using HTTPS or SSH.